# How to use edit button in Datagrid to show modal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am currently trying to find a way to show a modal whenever i click on the edit button on my table. Here is my front code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class=" row col-sm-6 panel-body">          
        <asp:DataGrid CssClass=" table table-borderless" OnItemCommand="PO_Form_ItemCommand" ID="PO_Form" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
               <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" Text="Edit" CommandName="grdEdit"></asp:ButtonColumn>                    
               <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="LinkButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="grdDel"></asp:ButtonColumn>
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PO_no" HeaderText="PO No." />
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="supplier_name" HeaderText="Supplier name" />
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="flight_no" HeaderText="Flight No." />
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="bkg_date" HeaderText="Booking Date" />
             <asp:BoundColumn DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
         </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
        </asp:DataGrid>
    </div>

   <%-- Modal top --%> 
    <div id="editmodal" class="modal" runat="server" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <%-- Modal Content --%>

            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

   <%-- Modal Bottom --%>
```

It would really be helpful if there is someone who understands my situation. Thank you.

Comment: Check out JQuery or Bootstrap or other front end framework. The docs will have examples of how to use their modals.

Comment: The edit button is not meant to open a Modal but to show the EditTemplates. You need to create your own buttons for opening the modal.